# Regex failure in matching

Tags: android, regex

I have a regex where I try to find this pattern in a text 15:30:55 (it's time). And the Pattern.compile is giving out an error `PatternSyntaxException: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR`

Here is my code

```
Pattern.compile("[0-9]{1,2}[:][0-9]{1,2}[:][0-9]{1,2}");
```

Comment: I think the pattern should be `[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}`, but that aside, it looks valid.  Can you post the entire Java code?

Comment: You should not put `:` into a character class as the first char. `[:]` => `:` and it will work. `[-:]` works, but `[:-]` won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing square brackets between colon characters in your regex: `[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}`

Comment: The regex looks good but it could be more succinct e.g. `\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}`

Comment: @hoipolloi Yeah this looks better. I just intended to correct the actual problem. Thanks

Comment: Worked pretty good. Using that now